# How to setup registration and signals in django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-registration, django-2.0

Can someone help me figure out what i am doing wrong trying to setup authentication and signals to work along with the models created in django 2.0.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(foo)
    location = models.CharField(foo)


    # Override save method
    # Run after the method is saved to add signal functionality below
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Profile

Profile = get_user_model()

class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(foo)
    first_name = forms.CharField(foo)
    last_name = forms.CharField(foo)
    password = forms.CharField(foo)
    password2 = forms.CharField(foo)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .models import Profile
from django.conf import settings

def register(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('accounts:login')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", context)
```

Foo = just a placeholder

The code above create the user but not the profile associated to it.

Any help would be much appreciated.